# JTextField and JTextArea

Tags: java

**What is the different between JTextField and JTextArea? Is this possible to work with this two classes in a one class?**

Answer (score 10):

In summary, a JTextField is a one-line text field, whereas a JTextArea can span over multiple lines.

The differences are clearly explained in the documentation: [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) *and* [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Of course, you can use them in the same class. There would be zero conflicts between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can always refer to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) for such kind of question.

You can work with both classes in one class. The main difference is the size, since JTextField are one line and JTextArea have columns and rows. (Which makes suitable for lots of information)

Comment: Can you give me an example with these two classes in a one class?