# What is the fundamental difference between a JTextField and a JTextPane?

Tags: textarea

I am only a beginner in Java. I would like to know the difference between a `JTextField` and a `JTextPane` in Swing.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714664/jtextfield-and-jtextarea

Comment: Im referring to JTextPane and not a JTextArea...i know what a JTextArea is.

Comment: Sorry my bad, refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JTextField renders an editable single-line text box. A user can input non-formatted text in the box. To initialize the text field, call its constructor and pass an optional integer parameter to it. This parameter sets the width of the box measured by the number of columns. It does not limit the number of characters that can be input in the box.

JTextPane is used for stylizing a document and for representing it graphically and has embedded images and other components. It is a subclass of JEditorPane which forms the base for styled-components for the text provided by Java Swing Package. This can be also used for adding custom text formats and for unstyled text, an ordinary text area is used. JTextPane makes the use of styled documents using a StyledDocument interface as its model. Document interface is the parent from which the StyledDocument interface is derived. The document interface is also the default model for JTextPane.

More information in:
https://www.educba.com/swing-components-in-java/